# Make icon of airDatepickerInput clickable

Tags: r, events, shiny, click

I'm looking for a way to fire this line of code:

```
onevent('click', '???' ,{ print( 'hey1!!') })
```

or

```
onclick('DateRange' ,{ print( 'hey1!!') })
```

but ONLY when the user clicks on the calendar icon of an `airDatepickerInput`

but I don't know how to target the icon since it has no ID of its own.

Targeting `'DateRange'` will not work as it will also trigger when clicking in the date range field, and that's unwanted.

The reason I want this is because I want the option to open a modal dialog that shows a plot with the date distribution of my data files the user is filtering for in my app.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(

    airDatepickerInput(
        inputId = "DateRange",
        label = "Select multiple dates:",
        placeholder = "You can pick 5 dates",
        multiple = 5, clearButton = TRUE
    ),
    verbatimTextOutput("res")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$res <- renderPrint(input$DateRange)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of the shinywidget package has updated the `airDatepickerInput` so that the button on the side can now be observed.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
    airDatepickerInput(
        inputId = "DateRange",
        label = "Select multiple dates:",
        placeholder = "You can pick 5 dates",
        multiple = 5, clearButton = TRUE
    ),
    verbatimTextOutput("res_date"),
    verbatimTextOutput("res_button")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$res_date <- renderPrint(input$DateRange)
    output$res_button <- renderPrint(input$DateRange_button)
observeEvent(input$DateRange_button, { 
    print(input$DateRange_button)
    })
    }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```